# How to call URL with Arduino Ethernet shield?

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega, shields, ethernet

I'm working on Arduino and Ethernet shield.

I need to call a URL. How can do it? (This URL is HTTP API to send an SMS to my phone).

1. url:
   http://api.clickatell.com/http/sendmsg?user=mohammed.atha&password=********&api_id=3539384&to=********&text=hello

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the **EthernetClient**. [link](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/WebClient)

The exemple using your API call is:

```
if (client.connect(server, 80)) {
    Serial.println("connected");
    // Make your API request:
    client.println("GET /sendmsg?user=mohammed.atha&password=********&api_id=3539384&to=********&text=hello HTTP/1.1");
    client.println("Host: api.clickatell.com/http/sendmsg");
    client.println("Connection: close");
    client.println();
}
```

Full example from Arduino.cc docs:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>

// Enter a MAC address for your controller below.
// Newer Ethernet shields have a MAC address printed on a sticker on the shield
byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };
// if you don't want to use DNS (and reduce your sketch size)
// use the numeric IP instead of the name for the server:
//IPAddress server(74,125,232,128);  // numeric IP for Google (no DNS)
char server[] = "www.google.com";    // name address for Google (using DNS)

// Set the static IP address to use if the DHCP fails to assign
IPAddress ip(192,168,0,177);

// Initialize the Ethernet client library
// with the IP address and port of the server 
// that you want to connect to (port 80 is default for HTTP):
EthernetClient client;

void setup() {
 // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
   while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for Leonardo only
  }

  // start the Ethernet connection:
  if (Ethernet.begin(mac) == 0) {
    Serial.println("Failed to configure Ethernet using DHCP");
    // no point in carrying on, so do nothing forevermore:
    // try to congifure using IP address instead of DHCP:
    Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
  }
  // give the Ethernet shield a second to initialize:
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("connecting...");

  // if you get a connection, report back via serial:
  if (client.connect(server, 80)) {
    Serial.println("connected");
    // Make your API request:
    client.println("GET /sendmsg?user=mohammed.atha&password=********&api_id=3539384&to=********&text=hello HTTP/1.1");
    client.println("Host: api.clickatell.com/http/sendmsg");
    client.println("Connection: close");
    client.println();
  } 
  else {
    // kf you didn't get a connection to the server:
    Serial.println("connection failed");
  }
}

void loop()
{
  // if there are incoming bytes available 
  // from the server, read them and print them:
  if (client.available()) {
    char c = client.read();
    Serial.print(c);
  }

  // if the server's disconnected, stop the client:
  if (!client.connected()) {
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println("disconnecting.");
    client.stop();

    // do nothing forevermore:
    while(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: how this can help me !!! 
plz help me

Comment: Just look at client.connect(server, 80) in code in the example, i've changed to work with your API call.

Comment: thnx thnx thnx :D

but why use google.com as server ? (char server[] = "www.google.com";)

Comment: Is there a need for subnet and default gateway ?

Comment: This is just to check if you have internet connection, simulating a ping in the google server. If it responds you have connection and then you make your API call, you can ignore this if you don't want to check for internet connection.

Comment: You don't need the default gateway

Comment: serial monitor (connecting...
connected
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Length: 54
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Thu, 30 Apr 2015 21:40:03 GMT
Server: GFE/2.0
Connection: close

<html><title>Error 400 (Bad Request)!!1</title></html>
disconnecting.) 

why bad request ?

Comment: vitor leal ????

Comment: @MohammedAthamneh please vote in the answer if it helped you ;)